# Use firebase unique key for ng-select value

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Angular: 8.2.12

What I want to do: 
A form where users create a new product and select packaging products for it (documents in another collection). Those packaging products can change (e.g. price) so I want to connect them by the unique key firebase created for those documents.

My HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="packagingProducts | async"
  bindLabel="title"
  placeholder="Select item"
  appendTo="body"
  multiple="true"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedPackaging"
  formControlName="packaging"
  bindValue="key">
</ng-select>
```

As you can see I try to save the unique key firebase created for the document with bindValue="key" which is wrong I guess because it's stored in the firebase as "null".

Items in my component.ts

```
packagingProducts = this.db.collection('packaging').snapshotChanges();
```

Seems like I can use everything within the document (e.g. title) but I don't know how I can use the firebase unique key (e.g. fBcRUsbEl2Xxka5MKkHu).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I found a proper solution. Stumbled upon this here: 
https://javebratt.com/angularfire-idfield/

Getting the items for my ng-select:

```
packagingProducts = this.db.collection('packaging').valueChanges({ idField: 'packagingproductId' });
```

My HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="packagingProducts | async"
  bindLabel="title"
  bindValue="packagingproductId"
  placeholder="Select item"
  appendTo="body"
  multiple="true"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedPackaging"
  formControlName="packaging">
</ng-select>
```